# How to mask numpy array with another numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

```
x = np.array([
  [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [1,2,1]],
  [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [3, 5, 8]]
])

z = np.array([
  [1, 0, 1],
  [0,1, 0]
])

#output
[
  [[1,2,3], [0,0,0], [1,2,1]],
  [[0,0,0], [4,5,6], [0,0,0]]
]
```

How to generate that output from `x` and `z` using numpy builtins (no `for` loop)?

Comment: `x*z[...,None]`?

Comment: @Divakar That works, thank you. Could you please provide a documentation for this kind of operations, if any?

Comment: This could be a good start - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html. Also look for None/np.newaxis.

Comment: `x*np.dstack((z,z,z))` will do as well, however @Divakar's answer is far better